# Quick framework crash XCTest library not loaded for arch x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

#### What did you do?

Installed Quick framework using pod

```
 pod 'Quick'
```

#### What did you expect to happen?

Run the Demo app without crashes

#### What actually happened instead?

App crashes on startup:
dyld[11272]: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
Referenced from: /Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8930165E-1256-413E-AE71-B81B78C23799/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D3BCC75-C97C-4F02-96C2-426D3E894DD6/QuickDemo.app/QuickDemo
Reason: tried: '/Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickDemo-hjyhkpgeditvlnbkokgocjlflslb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'armv7,armv7s,arm64,arm64e', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/swift/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8930165E-1256-413E-AE71-B81B78C23799/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D3BCC75-C97C-4F02-96C2-426D3E894DD6/QuickDemo.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8930165E-1256-413E-AE71-B81B78C23799/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D3BCC75-C97C-4F02-96C2-426D3E894DD6/QuickDemo.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8930165E-1256-413E-AE71-B81B78C23799/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D3BCC75-C97C-4F02-96C2-426D3E894DD6/QuickDemo.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'armv7,armv7s,arm64,arm64e', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/swift/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8930165E-1256-413E-AE71-B81B78C23799/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D3BCC75-C97C-4F02-96C2-426D3E894DD6/QuickDemo.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8930165E-1256-413E-AE71-B81B78C23799/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D3BCC75-C97C-4F02-96C2-426D3E894DD6/QuickDemo.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8930165E-1256-413E-AE71-B81B78C23799/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D3BCC75-C97C-4F02-96C2-426D3E894DD6/QuickDemo.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file)
Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
Referenced from: /Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8930165E-1256-413E-AE71-B81B78C23799/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D3BCC75-C97C-4F02-96C2-426D3E894DD6/QuickDemo.app/QuickDemo
Reason: tried: '/Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickDemo-hjyhkpgeditvlnbkokgocjlflslb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'armv7,armv7s,arm64,arm64e', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/lib/swift/XCTest.framework/XCTest' (no such file), '/Users/aimoresc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8930165E-1256-413E-AE71-B81B78C23799/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/2D3BCC75-C97C-4F02-96C2-426D3E894DD6/QuickDemo.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest

#### Environment

List the software versions you're using:

- Quick: *5.0*
- Xcode Version: Version 13.2.1 (13C100)
- Swift Version: 5
- CocoaPods: 1.11.2

Answer (score 1):

The XCTest framework is only available/loadable from test bundles, and it looks like I was trying to link/use Quick from your app target? changing the .podfile so that you only link Quick with your test target(s).

For example:

```
target 'QuickDemo' do
  # List of pods for the app target
end

target 'QuickDemoTests' do
  pod 'Quick'
end
```